# How to write a Circle Equation?

Tags: circles

How can we write a circle equation (in 3D) with the know values of circle radius, center position in 3D, and the normal vector that is perpendicular to the plane that circle is lying on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In 3D, intersect equation of the sphere with that of the plane ?

Comment: What kind of equation do you want? E.g. a system of equalities (like Mauro suggests),  or a parametric equation?

Answer (score 0):

$$((\vec p-\vec c)^2-r^2)^2+(\vec n(\vec p-\vec c))^2=0$$

or

$$\vec p=\vec a\cos\theta+\vec b\sin\theta+\vec c$$

where

$$\vec a=r\frac{\vec n\times\vec m}{\|\vec n\times\vec m\|},\vec b=r\frac{\vec a\times\vec n}{\|\vec a\times\vec n\|}$$ and $\vec m$ is an arbitrary vector not parallel to $\vec n$.